# How to get redis->lpush() return value in php?

Tags: php, redis

I was wondering can I get return value of $redis->lpush in php? I tried to print out the return value, but it seems there's nothing, then I googled it online, some doc says this method will return the length of the list, which confused me.

```
         $id = $this->post('id');
         $info = $this->PushModel->getPush($id);

         if(empty($info)){
             $this->json(Constant::FAILURE);
         }

         $gameId = $info['game_id'];
         $title = $info['title'];
         $content = $info['content'];
         $pushInfo = "$id|$gameId|$title|$content";

         $redis = $this->redis();
         $ret = $redis->connect(REDIS_HOST, ZGH_REDIS_PORT);

         $res = $redis->lPush(REDIS_HRGAME_PUSH_BATCH_KEY,$pushInfo);

         print_r($ret);
         print_r($res);exit;
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean - this works fine:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/php -f
<?php
   $redis = new Redis();
   $redis->connect('127.0.0.1',6379);
   $key = "MyFunkyKey";

   # Start with a clean slate
   $res = $redis->del($key);
   var_dump($res);

   # LPUSH key twice
   $res = $redis->lPush($key,1);
   var_dump($res);
   $res = $redis->lPush($key,1);
   var_dump($res);
?>
```

**Sample Output**

```
int(1)
int(1)
int(2)
```

---

Here's my version info:

```
$ pecl info redis

About pecl.php.net/redis-4.0.2
==============================
Release Type          PECL-style PHP extension (source code)
Name                  redis
Channel               pecl.php.net
Summary               PHP extension for interfacing with Redis
Description           This extension provides an API for communicating
                      with Redis servers.
Maintainers           Nicolas Favre-Felix <n.favrefelix@gmail.com>
                      (lead)
                      Michael Grunder <michael.grunder@gmail.com>
                      (lead)
                      Pavlo Yatsukhnenko <p.yatsukhnenko@gmail.com>
                      (lead)
Release Date          2018-04-25 11:28:55
Release Version       4.0.2 (stable)
API Version           4.0.2 (stable)
License               PHP (http://www.php.net/license)
Release Notes         phpredis 4.0.2

                      This release contains only fix of exists method
                      to take multiple keys
                      and return integer value (was broken in 4.0.1)
                      Thanks @RanjanRohit!
Required Dependencies PHP version 5.3.0-7.9.99
                      PEAR installer version 1.4.0b1 or newer
package.xml version   2.0
Last Modified         2018-05-31 06:54
Previous Installed    - None -
Version
```

Comment: thanks Mark, I checked my redis installation info on server,there is something wrong, so it's a installation thing. thank you.